# scala list match

Tags: list, scala, match

```
List(1,2) match {
  case List(1,_) => println("1 in postion 1")
  case _ => println("default")
}
```

compiles / works fine.
So do

```
List(1) match ...
List(3,4,5) match ...
```

but not

```
List() match ...
```

which results in the following error

```
found : Int(1)
required : Nothing
             case List(1,_) => println("1 in postion 1")
```

Why does List() try to match List(1,_)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `List()`, the type inferred is `Nothing`, which is subtype to everything.

What is happening is that Scala gives an error when you try impossible matches. For example, `"abc" match { case 1 => }` will result in a similar error. Likewise, because `List(1, _)` can be statically determined to never match `List()`, Scala gives an error.

Answer (score 12):

`List()` has type `List[Nothing]`.  If you use `List[Int]()` it will work as you expect.

(In general, types are as restrictive as they can possibly be; since you have made a list with nothing in it, the most-restrictive-possible type `Nothing` is used instead of `Int` as you intended.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because...

```
scala> implicitly[List[Nothing] <:< List[Int]]
res3: <:<[List[Nothing],List[Int]] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[List[Int] <:< List[Nothing]]
<console>:6: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e:<:<[List[Int],List[Nothing]]
       implicitly[List[Int] <:< List[Nothing]]
```

Comment: What this means is that `List[Int]` is coercible to `List[Nothing]` but the other way round is not possible.